# Remove Profile Center from Subscription Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, profile

Is there a way to remove the link to the Profile Center when I use the Unsubscribe Center?  The unsub center (%%unsub_center_url%%) goes to a page that has a link to the profile center.  Is there a different unsub URL I should be using?

We are not allowing any updates to people's profiles at this time.  The profile page doesn't have any profile info that one can update.

Is there any way to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  It used to be that you could have SFMC Support alter the stock Subscription & Profile Center Pages with what they called "brand tags".  They won't do it anymore.

Comment: Thanks Adam - that is incredibly disappointing.  Seems like such a basic feature to give some customization control over the unsub page.  Other than setting up a SFMC landing page, is there a way to self host the unsub page and push unsubs back in to SF and MC that you know of?

Comment: Sure, you can use the FuelSDK to do these functions on an external site, however there are AMPScript and SSJS functions that make Microsites/CloudPages an easier option.